# rails cancan gem uninitialized constant CanCan::Ability::I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, activesupport

I want to disable access to a Pages controller for users having role "author", using cancan (by Ryan Bates).

The PagesController is as follows

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @page = Page.new
    authorize! :update, @page
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

This is returning uninitialized constant CanCan::Ability::I18n
Note that the same thing happens when I use 
    load_and_authorize_resource 
filter instead of 
    authorize! :update, @page

I am using Rails 2.2.3.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue?
Thanks

Adding the ability.rb code:

```
class Ability
include CanCan::Ability

def initialize(current_user)
    user = User.find(:first, :conditions => ["username = ?", current_user])
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role?('admin')
      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, WpArticle
    elsif user.role?('moderator')
        can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role?('author')
        can :create, WpArticle
        can :update, WpArticle
        can :read, WpArticle
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I18n refers to internationalization (e.g. different languages). Are you running Rails in a language other than english?

Comment: To better assist you with this will you also post your `ability.rb` file.

Comment: @AlexPeattie Some tables in the MySQL db use collation type latin1_swedish_ci, others use utf8_general_ci. Do you think this is an issue? Thanks

Comment: @janders223 Added the ability.rb code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the i18n gem. Once installing, it should hopefully work.